# mod_headers not sending headers when file is PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, apache-2.2

I've got my .htaccess file set to the following:

```
 Header set MyHeader "I'm Set!"
```

If I go to that directory (`http://example.com/test/`), which has no default index file, and view the network activity (in this case with Chrome), I can see that the header is being sent.  If I go to a php file (`http://example.com/test/test.php`), the header isn't sent.

I've created an index.html (with simply `<pre>Hi` as the content) and it gets sent. I change the file name to `.php`, no header. If I change the orignal `test.php` to `test.html`, it outputs the garbage-looking code, and the header is sent. If I change `test.php` to `test.png`, I get a broken image icon, and the header is sent.

So, without testing beyond the above in terms of mime-type and file extensions, it appears only `.php` files (legit or otherwise) are either set to not have .htaccess rules apply or specifically the mod_headers directives.  But I don't know how to test for this and because it's a shared server, I don't have `httpd.conf` access to poke around.

Any ideas as to why apache would skip sending headers for php files?

I've also tried:

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
     Header set MyHeader "I'm Set!"
 </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Updating from PHP/CGI to PHP/FastCGI seems to have fixed it. I'm still very eager to get feedback if anyone knows what the root cause was.

Comment: Anthony, did you use mod_fastcgi? I experience exactly the same behavior and it seems to me that mod_fastcgi breaks mod_headers functionality. I posted this bug report yesterday: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache-mod-fastcgi/+bug/1368308

Comment: same here :/ any news or workaround that? I can't imagine this is not a problem in more cases out there...

Answer (score 5):

This is expected behavior when running CGI scripts.  From the latest (2.4) version of [the mod_headers docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header):

> The default value of onsuccess may need to be changed to always under
>   the circumstances similar to those listed below. Note also that
>   repeating this directive with both conditions makes sense in some
>   scenarios because always is not a superset of onsuccess with respect
>   to existing headers:
>
> [...]
>   You're modifying or removing a header generated by a CGI script, in which case the CGI scripts are in the table corresponding to always and not in the default table.

The original issue (with, perhaps, a better explanation) is in [Bug 49308](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49308).

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, using `Header always set MyHeader "I'm Set!"` should have solved the issue. I think I found an answer where someone suggested that and it didn't work for the OP in that case either. But I'm also pretty sure they said to try `Header set always`, which may have been why that suggestion failed.

Comment: Nope, I take it back. I ctrl-z'd to that attempt and it was `Header always set`.  Am I just misreading the quote?

Comment: In your original question you don't have that specified; are you sure its set?  It should be something like `Header always set MyHeader "I'm Set!"`, according to your example.

Comment: Well, I did try it, though without the endorsement of Apache, so I may have given up on one try. And now that it's working, I'm stuck with just assuming it was the switch from CGI to FastCGI, but I'm suspicious all around.