# How do I allow users to override X-Frame-Options when using Apache + PHP-FPM?

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, php-fpm, fastcgi, http-headers

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server running Apache + PHP-FPM + FastCGI, serving user home pages. For security, I have enabled in Apache's configuration:

```
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
Header set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin"
Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
```

`AllowOverride FileInfo` is set, so users can use `Header` directives in `.htaccess` files for more control, if they need it. However, it seems Apache doesn't honour that when using PHP with CGI ([mod_headers not sending headers when file is PHP](https://serverfault.com/questions/383011/mod-headers-not-sending-headers-when-file-is-php)), and that, even with `Header always`, `.htaccess`  `Header` commands are ignored for PHP files.

My next thought was letting the user modify their PHP code to use [the PHP `header` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), so that they can set it to X, and I can use `setifempty` to apply this only if the user hasn't. After a bit of experimenting, I found that these entries work:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin" env=!SCRIPT_NAME
Header always setifempty X-Frame-Options: "sameorigin" env=SCRIPT_NAME
```

Without the `env` tests, I found that the first command, even if it was `setifempty`, or `merge`, would add a header, so that you'd see two `X-Frame-Options` in the headers.

Now, is that the correct way of going about this? If the `env=SCRIPT_NAME` test sufficient, or is there a better test for determining whether the request will be handled by PHP-FPM/FastCGI or Apache itself?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I just ran into the same problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I think those two `Header` lines worked well enough for me that I didn't investigate much more.

Comment: Our problem is that, even though we use `setifempty`, all headers are sent twice - once from the configuration in `.htaccess` and once from using `headers` in PHP :(